# Instagram Auth Broken?

Tags: api, oauth, instagram

We just noticed that our app which relies on Instagram as the primary login is no longer working. In investigating this further, it appears the callback URL for Instagram stopped working. Now whenever anyone logs in via Instagram or signs up via Instagram, they are taken to the Instagram app instead of being asked to authenticate or taken into our app experience.

I checked another app that I know if, called "Print Studio" and the same thing is happening to them.

Is this issue happening to anyone else? Any clue as to what is causing it and has anyone heard from Instagram on a possible fix?

Comment: Nice to see it’s not just me. http://stackoverflow.com/q/40228583/4288782

Comment: Yeah I've been trying to fix this for 3 hours....

Answer (score 5):

Yes. seems to effect all applications (at least the apps that are using the approved 3rd party API). I saw this issue few days ago and it got resolved by itself. I assume Instagram engineers are rolling some updates and broke something.

I suggest reporting an issue from the developer portal. https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/. as many reports as they receive, the better.

**UPDATE:**

The issue seems to be related to cookies / session persistent changes made on Instagram side.
To workaround the issue, redirect the user to the original auth url when you detect the user got to the Instagram homepage. Because the user is already logged in, this should pass the user to the correct redirect url without logging in again.

for example, in swift:

```
  // MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate
  override func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

   if let urlString = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString {

     if urlString == "https://instagram.com" || urlString == "https://instagram.com/" ||
      urlString == "https://www.instagram.com" || urlString == "https://www.instagram.com/" ||
      urlString == "http://instagram.com" || urlString == "http://instagram.com/" ||
      urlString == "http://www.instagram.com" || urlString == "http://www.instagram.com/" {

        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        self.refresh(nil) // reloads the original auth url
        return
      }
    }

    super.webView(webView, decidePolicyFor: navigationAction, decisionHandler: decisionHandler)
  }
```

Comment: Yep, I reported earlier today. Still not fixed, but I'm hopeful it will be tomorrow. When you said it got resolved by itself, that is to say you are currently using OAuth and the callback URLis working as expected? So weird.

Comment: Yes. the callback URLs started to work normally after the last issue last happened few days ago. I posted a workaround above if you're interested

Comment: You are a sweet prince, aporat

Comment: @aporat I am also facing the same problem. Are there any side-effects of this redirect, if Instagram fixes things? I wonder if I should do an update of the app or not...

Comment: @Alin I would wait if were you, the same problem here but I am not sure if an workaround is the best approach

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev well, it's been already more than 14 hours since the answer, and basically all my new users will fail to use the app, because of this. But I agree, waiting sounds like the best choice so far... The report page does not work anymore, not sure if it's really an error or they are telling us that they are working on fixing it.

Comment: @Alin yep ti does not, I think they received literally hundreds of these reports and that is why it is closed

Comment: Well, it seems that the problem persists... and no news about it and the question seems to have been asked 20 hours ago.

Comment: I hope Instagram will fix the issue today or tomorrow. the oauth process is clearly broken. also note that if you enter wrong password, no error shows up (as the cookies / session are not handled correctly). regardless, I suggest rolling that update under a remote settings flag that you can turn off / on. this workaround can and will probably cause issues, if left active.

Comment: I have noticed a side-effect. If the user types in the wrong password, it does not display the red "please try again" (or similar) error message. If the user then enters the correct username/password, it gives some sort of cookie error message.

Comment: a side effect of the workaround? I believe the error messages are not being displayed regardless of the workaround

Comment: I'm not sure. Perhaps. Disable the workaround and type in the wrong password. Then see if you get the red error. -shrugs-

Comment: Yes the wrong password is still an issue as of now :(

Comment: Good News . Looks like instagram fixed the issue.

Comment: yep it is alive :D

Comment: This issue has still not been fixed on any of the apps that I checked.

Comment: @BrianWhipp could you please explain further, what exactly is not working and how we can re-produce the error?

Comment: On any app I run that uses instagram login, after the user logs in they are not redirected to the callback URL.  Either they are directed to instagram.com and that opens, or there is an error message saying Redirect URL does not match callback url.  I tried this with 2 apps I made and 1 I downloaded from gitHub.  All 3 should be working and worked a few days ago.  But now none of them have a successful login.

Comment: Could this have anything to do with iOS 10.1?