# No redirect to callback URL when authenticating to Instagram

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, instagram, passport.js, instagram-api

I am having troubles with my server-side login flow to Instagram. I am using:

- `passport.js` (passport-instagram) in my Node.js server, at the domain `example.com`
- A simple `WebView` in my android client.

The issue is that **sometimes** after typing the credentials the client is **not redirected** to the callback url.

#### These are the URLs as seen from the client when everything is working:

- https://example.com/auth/instagram : user visits my server and is redirected to instagram
- https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fauth%2Fredirect%2Finstagram&client_id=XXXXX
- https://example.com/auth/redirect/instagram?code=YYYYY : we reach the callback url

#### These are the URLs as seen from the client when the flow is **not** working:

- https://example.com/auth/instagram : user  visits my server and is redirected to instagram
- https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fauth%2Fredirect%2Finstagram&client_id=XXXXX : same as before
- https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://example.com/auth/redirect/instagram&client_id=XXXXX
- https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&next=/oauth/authorize/%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A//example.com/auth/redirect/instagram%26client_id%3DXXXXX : here I type my credentials
- https://www.instagram.com/

As you can see, at the end of the login, instead of being redirected to my server, I end up in https://www.instagram.com/ (successfully logged in, by the way).

Why is this happening?

I have no idea myself. Everything seems properly encoded. Might be some Android `WebView` setting that has to be tweaked (but the same WebView works great with authenticating with other auth providers), might be some `passport.js` configuration error (but I am using it successfully for all other providers), ...

Comment: Seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40226215/4288782

Answer (score 2):

having the same issue on my end and have replicated it on other live apps that use Instagram connect.

I've filed a bug report with Instagram but their developer support is quite minimal and I'm not sure if I'll hear back.

That said, I have to assume this is impacting a number of apps and not just ours so hopefully they are working on a fix.

Comment: I did too. Let’s see.

Comment: Happens to my app too, the report options does not work on their side :)

Comment: It’s easy to fix though, just catch the `https://www.instagram.com` redirect and override with your redirect url.