# Instagram Oauth redirecting to instagram.com

Tags: api, instagram

after i validate from https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + clientId + "&scope=" + strScope + "&response_type=code&" + "redirect_uri=" + callbackUrl, instead of showing [image]

instagram is taking me directly into instagram.com

Comment: Looks like it's an issue with Instagram API http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226215/instagram-auth-broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Instagram solved this issue

**OLD MESSAGE**

> Looks like it's an internal issue with Instagram API - we have the
>   same issue and in the last 24h there are a lot of reports of this
>   issue on StackOverflow. I think the best thing what you can do is
>   report this issue
>   [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/register/) - more
>   developers will report it, more likely Instagram team will fix it.

Comment: i have a doubt, why the same thing is working for hootsuite

Comment: @Sameer I've just checked their Android app and it doesn't work - they have exactly the same problem as we do.

Comment: @Alin I guess Instagram Android team has more options to use than API dedicated for 3rd apps