# Instagram oAuth redirecting to instagram dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, instagram, instagram-api

Instagram oAuth behaving weird on oAuth call. After clicking login button with instagram. Popup asks me to login. When I do, it just takes me to my instagram dashboard - it doesn't ask me to authorize or give me the options . Not able to redirect it back to my website after login.

Ny idea what happening.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226215/instagram-auth-broken

Comment: Broken here too, and given the other questions, there are a few hours since it failed....